# C++ - Joining properties of a vector<custom_class> into a string

Tags: c++

I have a `std::vector<custom_class>` which I would like to join into a comma separated string.

I found the code:

```
std::stringstream s;
std::string delimeter = ",";
copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(s, delimeter.c_str()));
```

which is great to join a vector of a single type, such as `int`. However, I would like to join **only** a certain property of my `custom_class`.

Can I use `copy` to copy and join only a certain property of my `custom_class`?

For example, my `vector<custom_class>` looks like:

```
v[0].A = 1
v[0].B = 2
v[0].C = 3

v[1].A = 1
v[1].B = 2
v[1].C = 3

v[2].A = 1
v[2].B = 2
v[2].C = 3

v[3].A = 1
v[3].B = 2
v[3].C = 3
```

And I'd like to use the `std::copy` to only join those values of property `B` (as an example) to return the value:

```
2,2,2,2
```

Is something like this possible without looping through `v` explicity?

Comment: This is `std::transform`.

Comment: @Chris How would I actually perform the join though? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/ looks like I can transform each element, but how could I use it to concat a string with a specific delimeter?

Comment: You should create a functor that extracts only data from b and store it in another vector, then use copy with ostream_iterator.

Comment: @Brett, It works the exactly same way as the copy except the element copied is determined by your transformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use standard algorithm `std::transform` instead of algorithm `std::copy`

For example

```
std::transform( v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( s, "," ),
                []( const custom_class &c ) { return c.B; } );
```

The other way is to use algorithm `std::accumulate` declared in header `<numeric>` and function `std::to_string`

For example

```
std::string s = std::accumulate( v.begin(), v.end(), std::string(),
                                 []( std::string &s, const custom_class &c ) 
                                 {
                                     return ( s += std::to_string( c.B ) + ',' ); 
                                 } );
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer. Perfectly clear now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Joining a string is a little odd, since you need to treat empty containers specially. So it might be easiest to roll your own algorithm. Here's one that takes an extractor predicate argument:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template <typename C, typename E>
std::string join(char const * delim, C const & c, E && e)
{
  using std::begin;
  using std::end;

  auto it = begin(c), eit = end(c);

  if (it == eit) { return {}; }

  std::ostringstream os;

  os << e(*it);

  while (++it != eit) { os << delim << e(*it); }

  return os.str();
}
```

Usage example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v { { 1, 4 }, { 2, 8 }, { 3, 19 }};
  std::cout << join(" | ", v, std::mem_fn(&std::pair<int, int>::second)) << "\n";
}
```

If you just want to print out the elements themselves without applying an extractor, you can pass some kind of "identity" extractor, for example a suitable instance of `std::forward`. We can in fact bake this in as default arguments:

```
template <typename C,
          typename E = typename C::value_type const &(&)(typename C::value_type const &)>
std::string join(char const * delim,
                 C const & c,
                 E && e = static_cast<typename C::value_type const &(&)(typename C::value_type const &)>(std::forward))
```

Now we can say e.g.:

```
std::vector<int> w { 1, 4, 2, 8, 3, 19 };
std::cout << join(", ", w) << "\n";
```

Comment: I noticed you edited it but didn't reply, it was real question, I'm new to the moving stuff and wasn't sure :)

Comment: @NeilKirk: I had replied, but then deleted the comment after I made the edit. You're right. I was thinking that the `str()` member is a permanent member of the stream, so that `move(os).str()` would be useful, but it isn't (the string is generated on the fly), so that wasn't useful. Thanks.